# Trying to understand scala ^^ syntax

Tags: scala

I'm beginner in scala and looking at this tutorial : 
http://enear.github.io/2016/03/31/parser-combinators/

Event it is explained just below :

> The ^^ operator acts as a map over the parse result. The regex
>   "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*".r is implicitly converted to an instance of
>   Parser[String], on which we map a function (String => IDENTIFIER),
>   thus returning a instance of Parser[IDENTIFIER].

I dont understand this code snippet  :

```
def identifier: Parser[IDENTIFIER] = {
  "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*".r ^^ { str => IDENTIFIER(str) }
}
```

Can someone explain the ^^ operator and how it is mapped to a block code ?

Thanks

Comment: I've not used it before, but it just looks like syntactic sugar for `.map(...)`.

Comment: what is your scala version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines the operation that needs to be performed when the left-hand side expression is evaluated.

For instance, we have some code like this:

```
def symbol: Parser[Any] = "+" | "-" | "*"

def number: Parser[Int] = """(0|[1-9]\d*)""".r ^^ {string =>  string.toInt }

def expression = {
    number ~ symbol ~ number ^^ { case firstOperand ~ operator ~ secondOperand =>
      firstOperand + secondOperand
    }
  }
```

So, here in the *number* we will convert String to Int. This means that when we will use our parser like this:

```
parse(expression, "3 + 2")
```

It will return us 5, if we will not convert it and leave it as Strings we will get "32".